# Switching universal app to iPhone only

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios-universal-app

I started my project as a universal app, and now I want to change the app to iPhone only and release that first, then upgrade later to support iPad.

When I tried to change the app to support only the iPhone, it won't launch in the "iPhone mode" when I run it on my iPad or the iPad simulator, I just see a black screen, and the app crashes.

What I did when I was changing the universal to iPhone only:

1. I changed the Universal to iPhone in the "Deployment info" section
2. Removed the iPad references from the info.plist
3. Changed the targeted device family to iPhone in the build settings.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is error message?

Comment: It doesn't say anything but just takes me to place where I animate iAD banner coming up. But the problem is that the app DOESN'T even launch in the small iPhone mode as it should if it's iPhone only app so there must be something else wrong.

Comment: Did you remove the old app from the iPad and clean your project before installing the new non-universal app? It sounds like some update problem to me ...

Comment: @TheEye Did those now and still won't work. Also read on the apple dev page that this black screen can be caused by leaving the Main_iPhone storyboard in the project, removed that too and still doesn't work either.

Comment: After removing a storyboard from the project you must clear the caches all along the workflow. Otherwise, the storyboard is still there. Did you that??? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4/6247073#6247073

Comment: Also make absolute sure that your `UIMainStoryboardFile` is set correctly in the info plist.

Comment: @matt Ok it's solved now, I cleared the cache and the app opens fine! Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Can you guess that exactly the same thing has happened to me? :)))